# mysql join query

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables like this

```
Table 1

id name
1 ABC
2 DEF
3 GEF


Table 2
name meal
ABC  m1
ABC  m2
GEF  m1

Table 3
meal detail
m1   mutton
m2   beaf
```

How can I get output like this?

```
Id name meal_detail
1  ABC  mutton,beaf
2  DEF
3  GEF  mutton
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   SELECT t1.id,
          t1.`name`,
          GROUP_CONCAT(t3.detail) AS `meal_detail`
     FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.`name` = t1.`name`
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.meal = t2.meal
 GROUP BY t1.`name`
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies: nah, now I follow your formatting style everywhere ;-) Just cheated with saving correct but not formatted query to catch the first answer ;-P

Comment: @EarnWhileLearn: lucky me ;-)